# Resolving a TypeReference to a TypeDefinition in Mono.Cecil fails with Assembly Resolution Error

Tags: mono.cecil, assembly-loading

I'm trying to get a Mono.Cecil TypeDefinition from a .NET type and not having any luck.

I'm using code like this:

```
var type = typeof(MarkdownMonster.AppConfiguration);

var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(type.Assembly.Location);
var tr = a.MainModule.Import(type);  // this seems to work
var td = tr.Resolve(); // fails
```

but it fails with an assembly resolution error:

> GetConfigurationPropertiesTest [0:29.990] Failed: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException : Failed to resolve assembly: 'MarkdownMonster, Version=1.18.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException : Failed to resolve assembly: 'MarkdownMonster, Version=1.18.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>      at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
>      at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
>      at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
>      at Westwind.TypeImporter.TypeParser.ParseObject(Type type, Boolean dontParseMembers)

The assembly is obviously there, since the TypeReference import seems to work and produces a valid TypeReference.

The assembly in question is an EXE, and just for kicks I renamed it to a DLL but that had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of back and forth experimenting I found one (ugly) solution is to create a custom type resolver and basically forcing a hard type reference into it. It seems Mono.Cecil is able to resolve transient dependencies once it's found the main assembly, but not the top level reference.

To make this work I basically pass in the already resolved assembly reference. In my case I know the only reference I will need to return will be the top level reference so I hard code this. A more realistic example will have to use `AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly()` to read an assembly off disk or from a stream.

Here's is the code to create the AssemblyResolver:

```
    public class MonoAssemblyResolver : IAssemblyResolver
    {
        public AssemblyDefinition AssemblyDefinition;

        public AssemblyDefinition Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
        {
            return AssemblyDefinition;
        }

        public AssemblyDefinition Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
        {

            return AssemblyDefinition;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            AssemblyDefinition = null;
        }
    }
```

Note the cheat to pass in an already resolved assembly reference.

To resolve I can now use the following code:

```
var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(type.Assembly.Location,
            new ReaderParameters() { AssemblyResolver = resolver });

// assign the resolvedr
var resolver = new MonoAssemblyResolver();
resolver.AssemblyDefinition = a;

var tr = a.MainModule.Import(type: type);
var td = tr.Resolve();   // works now
```

This is crazy hacky, but can be adapted to be more generic (in my case not needed).

Still it would be much nicer if Mono.Cecil could automatically resolve the assembly - I don't understand why it's not finding the assembly in the first place since it lives in the current bin folder and the TypeReference can find it.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how it's normally done:**

```
        var assembly = @"c:\myassembly.dll";

        var resolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();
        
        // add .NET runtime dir for the sake of security
        foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            resolver.AddSearchDirectory(dir);
        }
        
        // add the assembly's directory
        resolver.AddSearchDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly));

        var mod = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assembly, new ReaderParameters { AssemblyResolver = resolver }).MainModule;
```

Regards